# how to implement absolute path in global scss file? VueJS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, path

I have the following webpack config in vue.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    'style-resources-loader': {
      preProcessor: 'scss',
      patterns: [
        "./src/styles/global.scss"
      ]
    },
    configureWebpack: {
      module: {
        rules: [{
          test: /\.svg$/,
          loader: 'vue-svg-loader'
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This enables me to use styles defined in global.scss in all my vue components without any explicit imports.

Now the issue is that in global.scss I've defined:

```
   @font-face {
    font-family: Averta-Bold;
    src: url('../assets/fonts/averta/Averta-Bold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('../assets/fonts/averta/Averta-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../assets/fonts/averta/Averta-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../assets/fonts/averta/Averta-Bold.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../assets/fonts/averta/Averta-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
}
```

and had been using the fonts without any trouble so far until I created a nested folder in my ./src/components so it became ./src/components/dashboard/ and after I created components in the dashboard dir, the fonts could no longer be used/located as I would then have to prepend another "../" to the font url in global.scss however this would break all the other components.

How do I add absolute paths in global.scss? I've tried "@/assets/xxxxx" but that didn't work.

Comment: Did you try `/assets/...` without the `@`?

Comment: All the `partial files` are bloated into the `main.scss` before execution so, you can try filePath relative to the `main.scss` file.

Comment: I tried /assets/... and it worked... I'm not sure why though... @ChrisG You may add it as an answer

Comment: Initially my paths were relative from global.scss to the fonts file location @ShivamSingh

Comment: It works because starting a relative path with `/` puts it behind the hostname, ignoring the current location. And why would you put the `@` there in the first place anyway?

Comment: I see. To answer your questions: I thought @ was an alias for "/src" in Vue

Comment: If you have time could you hop onto chat and explain this in more detail?

Comment: I just had a closer look at the other components and unfortunately they can no longer use the font so the answer didn't work

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the delay. But better late than never.
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#referencing-assets

> Note if you want to reference a file inside an npm dependency or via
> webpack alias, the path must be prefixed with ~ to avoid ambiguity

`@` is a webpack alias that points to `./src`. So to use it it needs to be prefixed with `~`.

`url('~@/assets/fonts/averta/Averta-Bold.eot');` would work 100%

If the `@` alias is not working or for some reason is not set, go to your `vue.config.js` file located in your project root folder and add this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
   chainWebpack: config => {
       config.resolve.alias.set('@', path.join(__dirname, './src'));
   }
}
```